# Call Java from C using JNI

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I'm trying the following code to call a Java function performSHA() from C code. But I keep getting an error saying "request for member ‘DestroyJavaVM’ in something not a structure or union". I've checked several links online and seems like I'm using it as mentioned.

```
JavaVM *jvm;       
JNIEnv *env;      
JavaVMOption options[3];
JavaVMInitArgs vm_args; 
vm_args.version  = JNI_VERSION_1_2;

JNI_GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs(&vm_args);
options[0].optionString = "/home/amy/jni/";
vm_args.options  = options;

JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, &env, &vm_args);
jclass cls = (*env)->FindClass(env, "CallToBCLib");
jmethodID mid = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, cls, "performSHA", "ILjava/lang/String;");
(*env)->CallStaticVoidMethod(cls, mid, algo_id, tc->m1);
jvm->DestroyJavaVM();   <-- ERROR
```

Also is the usage of FindClass, GetStaticMethodID and CallStaticVoidMethod correct? performSHA is the Java function I'm calling and algo_id, tc->m1 are my args to the Java function...

Comment: https://github.com/clibs/sha1 Thank me later.

Comment: This isn't related to the problem with DestroyJavaVM but you're dereferencing env even though it is already a pointer. After that you try to access its members with the -> operator even though what you have is not JNIEnv * but JNIEnv.

Comment: @Daniel: `(*env)->` is fine, and simply how you do it in C. The `JNIEnv` itself is a pointer.

Comment: @Michael ahh I didn't see that the pointer was in a typedef... Why do people hide their asterisks in typedefs in code that is used in C :\

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by doing the following:

```
(*jvm)->DestroyJavaVM(jvm);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#DestroyJavaVM), you should provide a parameter of type `JavaVM *vm` to the `DestroyJavaVM` function:

```
jint DestroyJavaVM(JavaVM *vm);
```

Therefore, replace `jvm->DestroyJavaVM()` with `DestroyJavaVM(jvm)`.

Note that on the same page, there is an "Overview" with example where `DestroyJavaVM()` is called as in your code (`jvm->DestroyJavaVM()`) but this applies to C++ and you mentioned you are trying to call Java code from C.

Comment: I tried jvm->DestroyJavaVM(&jvm) and DestroyJavaVM(&jvm) but both don't seem to work. Is there anything wrong with the statements? DestroyJavaVM(&jvm) gives undefined reference error. The first option gives the same error as metioned in the post above...

Comment: You should use it in the following way `DestroyJavaVM(jvm)` (updated my answer).

Comment: DestroyJavaVM(jvm) this gives undefined reference error. "JNI_GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs", "JNI_CreateJavaVM" and "DestroyJavaVM" give undefined reference error...

Comment: And what does the make command do exactly? I'm afraid I won't be able to help you without these details.

Comment: [link](https://github.com/cisco/libacvp/blob/master/Makefile.in) This is the make file that is used when I run the "make" command...

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit too long to be in a comment so I'll put it as an answer.
I checked how you should access `DestroyJavaVM` in the jni source code:
The function is defined [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot/file/tip/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp#l3415) and this is the declaration:

```
jint JNICALL jni_DestroyJavaVM(JavaVM *vm)
```

At the [bottom of that page](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot/file/tip/src/share/vm/prims/jni.cpp#l3687) is a function invocation table for usage in C source code.

The specification gives us the definition of the JavaVM type [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/invocation.html#invocation_api_functions).
We can see that the definition of the JavaVM type is the function invocation table itself.

This means we need to take our `jvm` variable and access its `DestroyJavaVM` function,
while also passing the jvm instance itself, so the accessing code should look like this:

```
jvm->DestroyJavaVM(jvm);
```

I haven't tested this and it's a bit weird to call the function like that but I'm guessing this should work.